# JTextArea wrapping only once at the creation of the text area

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap

I have a `JTextArea` with

```
text.setLineWrap(true);
text.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Now I have the problem, that if I start the `GUI` containing some of this `JTextArea` the text is correctly wrapped into 3-4 lines. Now I resize the `GUI` to the rigth and the text is correctly expanded and just wrapped down to 1-2 lines. Now I start resizing the `GUI` back to the left, but the `JTextArea's` don't wrap back to the old state. They just stay wrapped to the 1-2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of layout you are using? You need to use one that fits on the size of the window.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    for (int i = 0; i < locales.length; i++) {
        sb.append(locales[i].getDisplayCountry()).append(' ');
    }

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(sb.toString());
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("All installed locales");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(scrollPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: @Vegas I'am using a GridBagLayout.

Comment: @Paul Vargas `new JTextArea(int, int);`